# Appending object to an object wipes previously appended data

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

This pen http://codepen.io/Irish1/pen/lbjdw shows what I am doing and demonstrates the problem.

I have a program which has a week object added to it, I can then add the name of the week and a description for it.  I then add a day to the week but in the process of adding this day it clears the previously entered name and description.  it only happens when you add a day for the first time so it has something to do with what I am doing in the ELSE path of my add day method here is my controller function

```
$scope.addDay = function(index) {

        if (isDefined($scope.program.weeks[index].days)) {
            $scope.program.weeks[index].days.push(
                {

                }
            );

        } else {
            $scope.program.weeks[index] = { 
                days: [
                    {

                    }
                ]
            };
        }
    };
```

The full code is detailed in the pen linked above if you need it.

How can I append that first days object without removing anything that has already been put in the weeks object?

Comment: If you need 11 levels of indentation to work with your data structure, I would suggest you try something else.

Comment: I know thanks, I will worry about refactoring when I have it working as intended

Comment: The addDay method in the question is the relevant code. I will have a look now and see what other parts might be relevant but I am pretty sure its the way I am adding the days: object in the else of the addDay function

Comment: Maybe this example might help you: Form builder: http://jsfiddle.net/ProLoser/bp3Qu/light/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning a new object to the `index` in the array. That's why all properties are "removed"

You probably just want to define the "days" property:

```
$scope.program.weeks[index].days = [ /* .. */ ]
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks.  Now to edit all the other methods that do the same thing :p